# Does Apache process an HTTP Post atomically - ie does it ensure the file is not available until it is completely downloaded

Tags: apache, post, https, atomic

We have an Apache server (Unix variant) that is going to be serving a small number of files in response to incoming requests. The files will be updated at random intervals (they contain real time data) by transferring replacement files from another system (no, we can't change this). The current proposed method of transferring the updates is via HTTPS POST that replaces the file in its entirety (there is some flexibility here). 
I want to know if Apache will process the incoming POST request atomically - ie. If an inbound GET request occurs at the same time as a POST update, will Apache ensure that the GET receives either the old version of the file or the new one, but not an error or some sort of composite.

Comment: By the way, it sounds like the semantics of HTTP `PUT` are more appropriate than `POST` here.

Answer (score 1):

Apache doesn't process POST requests. You will presumably have a CGI program a script that actually handles the POST process. The behaviour of the GET request depends on how this script overwrites the existing file. The safest way would be to download the POST data to a separate file and then rename it over the existing file, this will then result in the desired behaviour.